# Merge an MR when webbook return 200 status

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci, devops, cloudbees

I am working on pipeline where I have requirement of -

When an MR is raised on project repository(gitlab), an automation suite should run.
I have a job configured for automation suite in cloudbees.
So, I created a webhook on gitlab to trigger automation suite whenever MR is raised.

My automation suite successfully ran and webhook returned the status of 200.

Now I want this MR to be merged automatically whenever I get success status from webhook.

What is the easiest way to configure this auto merge ?

Can anyone help?

I tried checking all configurations from gitlab where is allows me to auto merge once pipeline successes.

But here they are expecting me to write git CI pipeline.

Okay I will write it, but I don't know how to add the success status of webhook in gitlab CI.